# Как запустить программу заново?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Учу **Python**, подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать так, чтобы после введения пользователем первой неправильной буквы программа выводила только надпись "GAME OVER" и не просила ввести вторую букву?

```
print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
print("С_рен_венький")
x=input("Первая буква:")
if x=="и":
    print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
y=input("Вторая буква:")
if y=="е":
    print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
```

Comment: В приведённом вами коде после первого вызова оператора if...else программа продолжается. Как вариант решения проблемы перенести код, начинающийся с ввода второй буквы под первый оператор if.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете просто второе условие перенести в первое:

```
print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
print("С_рен_венький")
x=input("Первая буква:")
if x=="и":
    print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
    y=input("Вторая буква:") 
    if y=="е":
        print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
    else:
        print("GAME OVER") 
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `exit()`:

```py
from sys import exit
print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
print("С_рен_венький")
x=input("Первая буква:")
if x=="и":
    print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
    exit()
y=input("Вторая буква:")
if y=="е":
    print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
    exit()
```

Или поместить это в функцию и использовать `return`:

```py
def main():
    print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
    print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
    print("С_рен_венький")
    x=input("Первая буква:")
    if x=="и":
        print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
    else:
        print("GAME OVER")
        return
    y=input("Вторая буква:")
    if y=="е":
        print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
    else:
        print("GAME OVER")
        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Также предыдущие два примера можно переделать так:

```py
from sys import exit
print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
print("С_рен_венький")
x=input("Первая буква:")
if x!="и":
    print("GAME OVER")
    exit()
print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
y=input("Вторая буква:")
if y!="е":
    print("GAME OVER")
    exit()
print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
```

Так как ни после `exit()`, ни после `return`, код не выполняется

Также советую почитать про `PEP8`, так например ваш код (ваша версия кода) должен выглядеть так:

```py
print("Игра: Вставь пропущенную букву")
print("Вставьте пропущенные буквы в следующее слово:")
print("С_рен_венький")
x = input("Первая буква:")
if x == "и":
    print("Отлично, продолжаем!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
y = input("Вторая буква:")
if y == "е":
    print("Прекрасно, вы справились!!!")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
```